# Identify the positions of a marker in sublists

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have a list of lists from which I would like to pick out the positions of the number `1` and then print out these positions for each sublist.

I am having some trouble collecting what I am printing into a list / matrix / array though. Below is my list of lists and the commands by which I find the positions of the 1's and print them out. Thanks.

```
ZeroCrossings = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}}

Do[Print[Flatten[Transpose[Position[ZeroCrossings[[t]], 1]]]], {t, 1,Length[ZeroCrossings]}]
```

> {3,9}
>
> {4,5,8,12,13}
>
> {4,12,13}
>
> {4,8,11,13}
>
> {4,9,12,13}
>
> {5,6,11}

Comment: Drop the `Print` and change `Do` to `Table`.  Is this what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primarily you just need to use `Table` instead of `Do` and `Print`.  Also you can simplify the code:

```
Table[Flatten @ Position[t, 1], {t, ZeroCrossings}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13}, {4, 9, 12, 13}, {5, 6, 11}}
> ```

See **Case #2** of: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)

It may be simpler to use `Map`:

```
Flatten @ Position[#, 1] & /@ ZeroCrossings
```

This is probably a bit advanced for you right now but you could also use:

```
GatherBy[Position[ZeroCrossings, 1], First][[All, All, 2]]
```

Or if you are using *Mathematica* 10:

```
GroupBy[Position[ZeroCrossings, 1], First -> Last] // Values
```

Comment: Like you said first, I used Table in place of Do to solve my problem. 

Table[Flatten[Transpose[Position[ZeroCrossings[[t]], 1]]], {t, 1, Length[ZeroCrossings]}]

Thanks for your help and advice!

Answer (score 5):

Another approach:

```
ZeroCrossings = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0}};

Map[Last, GatherBy[Position[ZeroCrossings, 1], First], {-2}]
```

> {{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13}, {4, 9, 12,
>   13}, {5, 6, 11}}

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `PositionIndex` in **Version 10**

```
(PositionIndex /@ ZeroCrossings)[[All, 2]]
```

Gives:

```
{{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13}, {4, 9, 12, 13}, {5, 6, 11}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
zeroCrossings = {{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0}};
```

**Using `SequencePosition`:**

```
SequencePosition[#, {1}] & /@ zeroCrossings /. {a_, a_} :> a
```

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
MapIndexed[If[#1 == 1, First@#2, Nothing] &, #] & /@ zeroCrossings
```

> {{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13}, {4, 9, 12,
> 13}, {5, 6, 11}}

Answer (score 4):

```
SparseArray[ZeroCrossings] @ "AdjacencyLists"
```

> ```
> {{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13}, 
>  {4, 9, 12,  13}, {5, 6, 11}}
> ```

Comment: Now the matrix tag is finally justified after all these years.

Answer (score 3):

```
Catenate @* Position[1] /@ ZeroCrossings
```

{{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13}, {4, 9, 12,
13}, {5, 6, 11}}

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use `Position` at level -1 and `SplitBy` as follows:

```
Map[#[[All, 2]] &, SplitBy[Position[ZeroCrossings, 1, -1], First]]

(*{{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13},
   {4, 9, 12, 13}, {5, 6, 11}}*)
```

Or using `Count` and `PartitionRagged` with `Position` at level -1:

```
#[[All, 2]] & /@ Internal`PartitionRagged[Position[#, 1, -1], 
Count[#, 1] & /@ #] &@ZeroCrossings

(*{{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13}, {4, 12, 13}, {4, 8, 11, 13},
   {4, 9, 12, 13}, {5, 6, 11}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since @kglr suggested, already, the use of `SparseArray` here's another way to go about it

```
Flatten /@ 
 GatherBy[SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] & /@ ZeroCrossings, 
  First]
```

> `{{3, 9}, {4, 5, 8, 12, 13, 4, 12, 13, 4, 8, 11, 13, 4, 9, 12, 13}, {5, 6, 11}}`

Comment: (+1) Nicely done, mate! :-)